# 2 command nmap in the same line

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, grep, nmap

Hello everyone and thanks for your help

I am using this nmap command to obtain host and IP information if port 80 is open.

> nmap -sV -iL test.txt | grep "Service information:" ; nmap --open -p
>   80 -iL test.txt -oG - | grep "/ open" | awk '{print $ 2}'
>
> Service Information: Host: HOSTNAME
>
> Service Information: Host: HOSTNAME
>
> XXX.XXX.XXX.XX
>
> XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX

What I want is to put it on the same line and get the following result:

> Service Information: Host: HOSTNAME, XXX.XXX.XXX.XX
>
> Service Information: Host: HOSTNAME, XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX

In the file test.txt I want to put a pol of routers ips that we have installed (now there are only two for test), the purpose of this is to analyze if they have port 80 open and router model installed and thus close it or not depending on whether the  User has changed the router.  (Bridge)